# Limit of a function with a defined integral 3

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

> Let $F$ be function defined as an integral
>
> $$F(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\textrm{d}t \quad \forall k\in \mathbb{N},\ x>0$$
>
> Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=0$

Indeed,

i'm tried to find such $M \in  \mathbb{R} \mid  F(x)\leq M $ with limit of M equal zero when $x \to \infty$

note that $t\geq1 \implies t^5+1\geq 1 \implies \dfrac{1}{1+t^{5}}\leq 1 \implies \dfrac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\leq e^{-xt} \implies \dfrac{t^k.e^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\leq t^k.e^{-xt} $

$$F(x)\leq \int_{1}^{\infty} t^k.e^{-xt}\textrm{d}t $$

- Am in the right way or please could you show me others ways

  > Another way  :
  >   note that $t^k=_{t\to \infty}o(e^{xt})$ then $\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{k}e^{-xt}=0$
  >   then $\dfrac{t^{k}e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}}{1+t^5}\underset{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\,0$ thus 
  >   $\forall k>0,\quad  \dfrac{t^{k}e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}}{1+t^5}\leq 1 \implies  \dfrac{t^{k}e^{-xt}}{1+t^5}\leq e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}$
  >   then 
  >   \begin{align}
  > F(x)&\leq \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}\textrm{d}t\\
  > &=\lim_{A\to \infty}\int_{1}^{A}e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}\textrm{d}t\\
  > &=\lim_{A\to \infty}[-\frac{2}{x}e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}]_{t=1}^{A}\\
  > &=\lim_{A\to \infty}[-\frac{2}{x}e^{-\frac{x}{2}t}]_{t=1}^{A}\\
  > &=\frac{2}{x}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\\
  >  0 \leq &\lim_{x\to \infty }F(x)\leq \lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{2}{x}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}=0
  > \end{align}
  >   Then  $$\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=0$$
- AM i right ??
- > note that $ \dfrac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^5}\leq e^{-xt}$ can we say that we've this statement true for all $k \in \mathbb{N},\quad   \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\textrm{d}t \leq  \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-xt}\textrm{d}t$

Comment: Are you familiar with the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes i do (lebegue)

Answer (score 3):

Since $F(x) \le \int_1^{\infty} t^ke^{-xt}\,dt$, you also have that $F(x) \le \int_0^{\infty} t^ke^{-xt}\,dt$. Do a change of variable and make use of a nice property of the $\Gamma$ function and you'll have your result.

Here's how I would continue. From my above argument,

$$F(x) \le \int_0^{\infty} t^k e^{-xt}\,dt.$$

Make a change of variable $\tau = xt$, then $d\tau = x\,dt$ and our inequality becomes

$$F(x) \le \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\tau}{x}\right)^ke^{-\tau}\frac{1}{x}\,d\tau.$$

Doing a little regrouping gives

$$F(x)\le \frac{1}{x^{k+1}}\int_0^{\infty}\tau^ke^{-\tau}\,d\tau.$$

This integral has a nice closed-form solution and it is in fact nothing more than $k!\,$. (You can prove this to yourself by induction or doing a few examples.) Thus

$$F(x) \le \frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}.$$

Can you see how this gets you what you want?

Comment: this is with gamma function let's say that i can't manupilate wih it

Comment: You don't need to use the $\Gamma$ function per se. There is a very nice expression for the integral $\int_0^{\infty} t^k e^{-t}\,dt.$ You can prove the result by induction - no high-powered math needed.

Comment: Check my update please

Comment: It's okay but much more work than what I suggested.

Comment: sorry i didn't mean it

Comment: No worries :). Does that help?

Comment: yes it's clear thanks

Comment: Check my update please

Comment: Minor typo, it should be $k!$, not $(k-1)!$

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks. I hate the definition of the Gamma function. I always get confused.

Comment: Me too!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

For $x \geq 1$ we have

$$
\left|\frac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\right| \leq \frac{t^ke^{-t}}{1+t^{5}} \in L_1([1,\infty)).
$$

Also, for every fixed $t \in [1,\infty)$ we have

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}} = 0.
$$

By the dominated convergence theorem we therefore have

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\,dt = \int_1^\infty 0\,dt = 0.
$$

Comment: that's awesome !