# Inequality in intergration

Tags: integration, inequality

i saw this in solution of some exercise they said that (the real exercise i already post it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851493/limit-of-a-function-with-a-defined-integral-3) )

> $$\dfrac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^5}\leq e^{-xt}  \Longrightarrow  \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{t^ke^{-xt}}{1+t^{5}}\textrm{d}t \leq  \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-xt}\textrm{d}t,\quad   \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

is that true and how they did to get off $t^k$

here is the source

[image]

Comment: It's not true for all $x$.  Is it saying that the inequality only holds for large enough $x$?

Answer (score 1):

$1+t^2 \geq 1$ for every $t\geq 0$. Take reciprocals. It is not clear why $t^k$ disappears, especially when $k \geq 6$.

Comment: yes it's  not clear i can post the hole source of solution that they made for it